# Writing to csv puts quotes around quotes and quotes around entire cell

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write an array to a csv but if the array cell has double quotes in it, it adds quotes like so:

example data in the array: The quick brown "fox" jumps

that same data in the csv: "The quick brown ""fox"" jumps"

If the first part is in quotes like so: "The quick" brown fox jumps, it does the same thing: """The quick"" brown fox jumps". So it is adding quotes around the part that has quotes and then adds quotes around the entire cell contents.

Here is my code that writes to the csv:

```
matrix = populateArray()
with open('phrases.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    for x in range(0,1):
        print(matrix[x])
        thewriter.writerow(matrix[x])
```

The output of `print(matrix[x])` is:

```
['The "quick" brown fox jumps', 'Lorem ipsum']
```

So you can see the data is formatted properly directly before it gets written to the csv, but at some point during the actual writing of the csv, it adds the extra quotes as described above.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Double quotes mean something special in CSV files. `csvwriter` adds turns one `"` into two because that's how quotes are escaped in the CSV standard. When you read it back in with the corresponding reader, it will be the same as `matrix[x]`. If you change this behavior, it's possible your output CSV file won't be readable to the same strings that you wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
with open('phrases.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
    for x in range(0,1):
        print(matrix[x])
        thewriter.writerow(matrix[x])
```

---

You need to specify that the writer shouldn't generate additional quotes (`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`):

> **[`Dialect.quoting`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quoting)**
>
> Controls when quotes should be generated by the writer
> and recognised by the reader. It can take on any of the `QUOTE_*`
> constants (see section Module Contents) and defaults to `QUOTE_MINIMAL`.

And will probably need to specify `escaprechar` too:

> **[`Dialect.escapechar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar)**
>
> A one-character string used by the writer to escape
> the delimiter if quoting is set to QUOTE_NONE and the quotechar if
> doublequote is False. On reading, the escapechar removes any special
> meaning from the following character. It defaults to None, which
> disables escaping.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just tried it and it says: 'quoting' is an invalid keyword argument for open().  I checked the python documentation and it doesn't mention anything about quoting. Any thoughts?

Comment: When not using a context manager, you should open the file separately and close it when finished. Regardless, when opening a csv you should specify "newline=''` (see the `csv` docs).

Comment: @martineau Agreed. I removed it anyway because context managers are more convenient .

Comment: @giorgos-myrianthous Thanks for the updated answer. That worked except it did give me the error: need to escape, but no escapechar set. I added in `escapechar='\\'` which then ran with no errors but now preceeds every quote with a "\". I assume this is not going to cause me problems as explained by @MarkPflug answer?

Comment: @user2382321 That's correct - I've missed the `escaprechar`.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct as per the RFC-4180 standard:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2

To explain a bit: quotes are placed around fields that contain delimiters. A field that contains a comma would have quotes around it so indicate that the entire quoted text is the field, and the included comma is part of the value, and shouldn't be interpreted as a field delimiter. However, that means that quotes also become problematic, as how would you represent a field that started with a quote? You have to escape the quotes, which is done by doubling them up.

This processing is necessarily to be able to unambiguously read the input values back out with their embedded commas and quotes.

A correctly implemented CSV library should reproduce the original values that you  wrote in, even though the representation within the CSV looks different.